# how to serial number automatically in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have table *studentinfo* with columns *admissionNo* and *studentId*. Now i need to generate serial no for *studentID* how?

Comment: u can use auto_increment

Comment: If you googled your question title, the first result that shows up pretty much answers it.

Answer (score 1):

u can try this :

```
create table studentinfo (studentId int auto_increment primary key,admissionNo varchar (25));
```